# Periodic location updates in a Service (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I am trying to implement a service that once started continues forever (unit OS forcibly closes it due to lack of resources). This services obtains user's location say every five minutes. In my implementation the service works if the application is sent to background **but stops when the application is terminated**.

Can you also suggest how to get periodic updates (e.g. get location after 5 mins)

**GeoFenceService.java**

```
public class GeoFenceService extends Service {

private Context mContext;

private List<TestMalls> mTestMalls ;
private MyLocationManager mLocationManager;
private HashMap<Integer, Double> mallDistances;

private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
private Looper mServiceLooper;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getBaseContext();

    this.mLocationManager = MyLocationManager.getInstance();
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid){

    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startid;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    return START_STICKY;
}

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper){
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Service running ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationManager.startListenLocation(mContext);

        while (mLocationManager.hasLocation()) {

            for (TestMalls t : mTestMalls) {
                mallDistances.put(t.mallId, (double) mLocationManager.distanceInMetersFromLocation(t.latitude, t.longitude));
            }

            Iterator bt = mallDistances.entrySet().iterator();
            while (bt.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<Integer, Double> pair = (Map.Entry<Integer, Double>) bt.next();
                Log.v("Hash Map Distances", "Id: " + String.valueOf(pair.getKey()) + " Distance " + String.valueOf(pair.getValue()));
                bt.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("Service", "done - finished");
}
}
```

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `PendingIntent` with the `getService()` method and add it to the `AlarmManager` to repeat every 5 minutes. Ensure that the `Service` stops itself after completing its work (i.e. call `stopSelf()` at the end).

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
            5*60*1000, pi);
```

Assuming that your `Service` works properly, this will work.

Comment: great..thanks..what about the service stops when the application is terminated

Comment: Once a `PendingIntent` is added to the `AlarmManager`, it will periodically start the `Service` after the specified interval *forever*, until the `PendingIntent` is removed from the `AlarmManager` and cancelled.